# How to scale SVG image to fill browser window?

Tags: layout, xhtml, svg, scaling, aspect-ratio

This seems like it ought to be easy, but I'm just not getting something.

I want to make an HTML page containing a single SVG image that automatically scales to fit the browser window, without any scrolling and while preserving its aspect ratio.

For example, at the moment I have a 1024x768 SVG image; if the browser viewport is 1980x1000 then I want the image to display at 1333x1000 (fill vertically, centred horizontally).  If the browser was 800x1000 then I want it to display at 800x600 (fill horizontally, centred vertically).

Currently I have it defined like so:

```
<body style="height: 100%">
  <div id="content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
         width="100%" height="100%"
         viewBox="0 0 1024 768"
         preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
      ...
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

However this is scaling up to the full width of the browser (for a wide but short window) and producing vertical scrolling, which isn't what I want.

What am I missing?

Comment: Inexplicably, I tried moving the inline style attributes to a CSS style block in the head, and after that it worked.  I don't know why it made a difference.  (Though I did need to add overflow: hidden -- otherwise there was a 4-pixel vertical scroll.)

Comment: And ... oh my god ... svg attributes are case sensitive! `viewbox` doesn't work!

Answer (score 207, accepted):

How about:

```css
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden }
svg { position:fixed; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0 }
```

Or:

```css
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden }
svg { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100% }
```

I have an example on my site using (roughly) this technique, albeit with 5% padding all around, and using `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed`:
http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml

*(Using `position:fixed` prevents a very edge-case scenario of linking to a sub-page anchor on the page, and `overflow:hidden` can ensure that no scroll bars ever appear (in case you have extra content.)*

Comment: And a late +1 for leaving that link up 2 years on.

Comment: Note that this solution relies on the `viewBox` attribute.

Comment: The link is _still_ there, nearly 4 years later. Good work, @Phrogz!

Comment: Yes, thanks @Phrogz... And just in case it ever goes down, I made a codepen version: http://codepen.io/cyanos/full/XbXxOQ/

Comment: And +1 for over 8 years

Comment: Wow, been trying to make svg responsive since last 2 days. Amazing answer, and thank you !

Comment: Thank you for this. +1 as this link is still active ... EXACTLY 11 years later. What a legend.

Answer (score 0):

I want to just add for those needing to have an svg fit both the width and the height without preserving the aspect ratio add preserveAspectRatio="none" -- e.g.

```
<svg id="burgerCover" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 745.45 704.55" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1{
        fill:#d8e720;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M0,0H745.45V593.18s-133,112.46-372.72,111.37C122.73,703.41,0,593.18,0,593.18Z"/>
</svg>
```