# Getting SVG to scale with browser/device window

Tags: svg

OBJECTIVE
I have an svg that I would like to scale with the browser window.

Parameters

a) It is to keep it's proportions (here a square)

b)to fit the bowser/device window to 80%

c)But to a maximum of 800px.

d) I'm not interested in javascript solutions

Code so far (although I've tried many combinations)
SVG root element, the preserve aspect ratio has been left to default

```
svg viewBox="0 0 800 800"
```

and with regards to html & viewport
HTML (embedding with object)

```
object type="image/svg+xml"  id="svgobject" data="question0final.svg"
```

CSS, things tried, amongst others...

```
#svgobject{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%}
```

(From; 
[How to scale SVG image to fill browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643254/how-to-scale-svg-image-to-fill-browser-window))

```
#svgobject{width:80%; max-width:800px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;}
```

I've read a number of good resources, but I can't work out my errors

FYI here are some of the better links I've found on SVG positiioning

[Do I use <img>, <object>, or <embed> for SVG files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files)

http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Web-SVG-Positioning.html

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-ii

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/16/resolution-independence-with-svg/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Scaling_of_SVG_backgrounds

(I find that SVGs as CSS backgound seem to pixelate)

Comment: Resolved by itself (so it was something I was doing...)

Comment: The procedure I was using was fine, settled on  #svgobject{width:80%; max-width:800px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;} for my css. Apologies. At least I put up some good links!

Comment: This isn't working for me. It seems that the SVG element is respecting the width/max-width attributes, but the elements inside the SVG are just being cut off, rather than scaling up/down.

Comment: @josiah sprague Check your viewBox is big enough for the image.

Answer (score 3):

Scaling the object won't work. You have to get reference of the svg element.

```
var svgs1 = $('object[id ^="svgobject"]');                            
var svgDoc = document.getElementById(svgs1[0].id).contentDocument;
var svgRoot = svgDoc.documentElement;
```

Now you have svg element in the variable `svgRoot`. So, calculate your scale value like this:

```
var desiredWidth=500; //this is your desired width 
var scaleVal=desiredWidth/$(window).width(); //now you have scale value

$(svgRoot).css("-webkit-transform","scale("+scaleVal+")");
```

Like this, you can scale the svg component with respect to the screen size.