# scaling an svg to be the width of the screen

Tags: css, svg

I have an enormous svg. I'd like to scale it to be 100% wide (the width of the screen). What would be the best way to do that, please?

html:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1368px"
 height="775px" viewBox="0 0 1368 775" enable-background="new 0 0 1368 775" xml:space="preserve">
...
```

css:

```
.svg {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%); /* center */
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
```

}

Comment: Why display none on something you want to see?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a <svg> element expand or contract to its parent container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919076/how-to-make-a-svg-element-expand-or-contract-to-its-parent-container)

Comment: @Paulie_D: Sorry, I've removed that css line -- it was something that in my program gets removed by jquery.

Comment: the linked answer isn't working for me. Can someone please help?

Comment: Answer was here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643254/how-to-scale-svg-image-to-fill-browser-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SVG header, wrapped around a `<div>` that controls the width, height using CSS.

```
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1368 775" enable-background="new 0 0 1368 775" xml:space="preserve">
    ...
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```