# How to scale my .svg to fill the entire viewport?

Tags: html, css, svg

My goal is to frame the entire page with the border defined in the svg image. I thought my `css` should do the trick, but the border doesn't scale to the browser window.
What should my .css file look like?
Should I modify the `svg` `viewbox`?

My Code:

```css
html {
  background: url(img/border.svg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p>some text.</p>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m0 0.1375h198.7v111.92h-198.7v-111.92m2.3812 1.8521v98.954c0 1.3229 1.0583 2.3812 2.6458 2.3812h191.29l0.26459-98.69c0-1.5875-1.0583-2.6458-2.9104-2.6458z" fill="#d9d9d9"/>
</svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scale SVG image to fill browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643254/how-to-scale-svg-image-to-fill-browser-window)

Comment: I tried that and i didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewbox` is 300 x 300  change that to 1920 x 1080 (your svg size) then that should do it and make it responsive.

check this code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p>some text.</p>
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1080;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#D9D9D9;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M0-0.7h1920v1081.5H0V-0.7 M23,17.2v956.2c0,12.8,10.2,23,25.6,23H1897l2.6-953.6c0-15.3-10.2-25.6-28.1-25.6
 L23,17.2z"/>
</svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [ https://ibb.co/c9dMDJ ] Unfortunately, it doesn't work. By the way: it has to work on a 4:3 monitor, too. I don't want the aspect ratio to be preserved. The image can be stretched!

Comment: well you didn't say that in your post!! and why the vote down? at least say why rather than just down vote the answer. and here I updated my answer @MarvinNoll

Answer (score 0):

You should change your viewbox dimensions its very small to be screen responsive.

make it something like `viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"` and then apply css

Answer (score 0):

You have several things wrong:

1. Your SVG is missing a closing `</svg>` tag.
2. Your `viewBox` values are wrong. They are bigger than your actual SVG contents.  It should be something like: `viewBox="0 0 199 112"`
3. To make the SVG ignore its aspect ratio and stretch to the parent container, you need to add `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

```css
svg {
  /* Example dimensions to show that svg stretches correctly */
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: linen;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 199 112" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="m0 0.1375h198.7v111.92h-198.7v-111.92m2.3812 1.8521v98.954c0 1.3229 1.0583 2.3812 2.6458 2.3812h191.29l0.26459-98.69c0-1.5875-1.0583-2.6458-2.9104-2.6458z" fill="#d9d9d9"/>
</svg>
```